# How can I change my BIOS splashscreen?

Tags: bios, splash

How can I change my BIOS splashscreen?

I have an AMD Athlon64 PC with Windows 7. I have a MS-7367 motherboard.
My BIOS = American Megatrends, Inc. v3.0. (date: 06/06/2007) (got the info from CPU-Z)

Comment: What do you mean by splash screen? What is it showing now? What do you want to change it to?

Comment: He probably means the screen the motherboard shows during POST.

Comment: no i mean that i want to change the boot logo (a.k.a splashscreen) that shows now at bootup... Is that possible and how?

Comment: I strongly urge you to not mess with the BIOS, as you can render your motherboard useless!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This will not work as the splash screen is saved onto your BIOS. The only way is to flash it across.**

I have never tried this, but I am pretty sure that this will work; no guarantees though.

1. Install [WinRAR](http://www.rarsoft.com/), a extracting software that has a free trial download, which is all you need.
2. Hunt around your laptop maker's website and look for a download of the latest BIOS for your laptop. Download it and place it in its own folder.
3. Right click on the file and choose "extract files" (this is where WinRAR comes in). Extract them and look around for a .gif file; you may need to extract some other files that you just extracted. You can extract almost any .exe file that is in the download.
4. Go through all the .gif, .jpg, .png files that you found and find the one that is shown when your computer boots up.
5. Replace the file with a new image file of the same name and extension.
6. After you have done that, now you have to package it all together. Select all the files, right click, and choose add to archive. Check create sfx archive, then click okay.
7. Double click on the file you just created!

**Warning: I would not reccomend this unless you have something that can restore your BIOS, if such a thing exists.**

Comment: Can you explain this procedure for the Asus X540S? The BIOS updates come as firmware (FW) files not recognized as archives. Rather, their processing is done by 'Windows BIOS flash utility' application

Comment: Please stop recommending WinRar, and recommend 7zip instead, which is opensource and completely free, not like WinRar...

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the BIOS/Motherboard maker lets you do. I have had an ASUS motherboard for a while, and ASUS provided a tool that that let me do exactly that. Never really used it though... I pretty much always just turn that splashscreen off, because I prefer to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

The only possibility to do this would be to change/hack the BIOS, and flash that customized BIOS onto your motherboard. But that's not a trivial task, nor is it easily done...and in the worst case you can use your Motherboard as a trivet afterwards.

Comment: So you can and it's possible. TutorialPoint never said it had to be done on the fly. Flashing a BIOS with another logo is indeed the only solution.

Comment: But is it worth risking bricking your machine to display an image that's only visible for a second or less?

Comment: @snark: You're right, I have to rephrase my answer a little. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that it currently shows a logo screen and you want it to show full POST messages (or vice versa) then look for an option in the BIOS which is something like "Quick Boot" or "Quiet Boot" or "Show Logo".

Comment: I tried it, but no, that's not what i want. I want to change the logo screen of the BIOS.

Comment: So my own customized logo screen for the BIOS startup

Comment: So it is the screen the motherboard shows during POST, the very first screen you see after you power up your pc.

Answer (score -2):

Run this command:-
Open cmd
Type bcdboot C:\Windows /s c: / f UEFI
Then u can see the logo for the whole boot up of windows too
Warning:-only for UEFI or EFI motherboards

Comment: Can you explain what this command will do?

Comment: This answer is more like a comment.  If you want it to be an answer you will need to provide more detail.  Please visit the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Comment: This is not the bios splash screen, this the next step, so basically the bios splash will appear and then the screen that you change in the UEFI/MBR.