# Is it possible to change the motherboard/bios vendor name?

Tags: motherboard, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change my BIOS splashscreen?](https://superuser.com/questions/116507/how-can-i-change-my-bios-splashscreen)

When we start the system we normally used to get the motherboard/vendor name for

e.g i'm having the system with mercury motherboard whenever i restart my system the mercury logo will get displayed(you ll have respected vendors) and the regular process will go on .. my question is

Is it there any possibility to change the name and logo of mercury(on my system &it differs based on your motherboard you are using ) on start up?

if you are an laptop user "you can see the laptop vendor name e.g "dell" "

For asus user's refer  Bon Gart's comment ,I am in search of answer those whom feel frustrated about the motherboard/bios splash screen and whom feel to change it

Comment: i cant place the right tag for my question any suggestions to place the tags also welcome

Comment: Asus provides a nifty utility that allows you to edit a BIOS update file, to alter the BIOS splash screen, before you actually flash a BIOS.... or reflash the Bios if you are just changing the logo.  On some Asus driver/utility discs, the utility is simply called MyLogo.  So, is it possible in general?  Yes.  Is it possible with a Mercury BIOS?  Mercury doesn't make a utility for this, so although a programmer *might* be able to hack a BIOS flash file to replace the Splash image, I don't know if I'd want to flash that on my BIOS.

Comment: @BonGart i stated example for better understanding sir,is it possible in general?

Comment: and *as I stated*, yes.  It is possible.  I said specifically "So, is it possible in general? Yes." This quote from my comment would indeed appear to answer your question about whether it is possible in general.

Comment: You will be better off looking at the manual for these motherboards. This question just needs a little bit of research on your own part

Comment: can anyone state the reason for downvote

Comment: @Journeyman Geek can you reopen the question since the "How can I change my BIOS splashscreen?" answers doesnt get worked and its not answer for my searchings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without specific tools from each motherboard manufacturer (or at least every motherboard BIOS **chipset** manufacturer) then there is no program that can do this in a generic fashion.

Each BIOS firmware will have information on display setup and, as you have seen, sometimes for particularly large manufacturers an image.

Somewhere in that firmware image you download from a motherboard manufacturer will be some data corresponding to that image that is potentially editable by humans but it may well be in a "raw" graphics format that no sensible "desktop" Paint like image editor will touch.

Once you have that image, and have edited it you then have the problem of putting it back into the firmware image for flashing back onto the motherboard.  In that firmware image is most likely to be a CRC checksum of some kind to make sure that the data is in tact and the BIOS firmware is not broken.  You'll then need to recalculate the CRC and stick that in the firmware file too.

Then you *might* be able to flash that BIOS to the motherboard you have and it might not kill your motherboard, *if you're lucky*.

Now another motherboard of a different type comes through the door.  You can't just flash your modified firmware to this new board because the BIOS chip is different due to hardware changes.  You'll keep meeting this problem with almost *every* motherboard you see, if you want them all to look the same then you either have to be the one dictating the BIOS software to begin with (like Dell can) or you face a world of pain hacking and kludging your way through them all.  Each with their slightly different formats for the code and image data, all stored in different locations within the firmware image.

Some people (like Asus) are kind and give you the tools, though most companies think it's a bit risky giving you those tools because it is more likely that you'll be regularly flashing your BIOS into an early grave and thus complain at them for a replacement because you were changing your boot screen every day.

Anyway, why should any normal user care about the BIOS boot screen?  No real user cares that much, the screen is only there for 10 seconds at most and provides almost no real information that a non-technical person will find useful or interesting.

You either need to be the one in power or the one in pain, you are not Dell.

If you desperately *have* to have the image in the BIOS screen the same across a lot of PCs you are best off standardising to one type of motherboard and then going to the manufacturer of that motherboard and asking them to customise it for you.  Chances are this will cost you though.

Answer (score 2):

Bios hacking is hugely risky, and will void your warranty, and cause other nasty things like premature baldness and extra toes.. maybe not the toes.

It is *possible* in some circumstances to do so - [intel](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-015474.htm) has a tool for that for some motherboards, but unless you're a OEM or know how to recover from a mucked up bios flash, its simply not worth the risk.