# How do I get rid of words on my BIOS splash screen?

Tags: boot, bios, dell-optiplex, splash

I have a Dell OptiPlex GX620 and on the BIOS splash screen above the Dell logo it says the name of a college and I would like to get rid of that so it’s normal.

I have tried to flash the BIOS by downloading the BIOS update and running it but it didn’t get rid of the name of the college and just updated the BIOS.

How do I remove these words form my BIOS splash screen?

Comment: The behavior you described is contained in memory that cannot changed.  In other words its not handled by the BIOS.

Comment: It's not the BIOS you want to update, it's the splash screen you want to change. Have a look and see if you can find a Dell BIOS spash screen changer for that machine model (I'm assuming you're OK to have the machine from the college?)

Comment: yes of course i bought it in an auction and am not sure how to get rid of that. perhaps you can share me a link for a bios splash screen changer?

Comment: I have been searching for a Dell BIOS splash screen changer and i cant seem to find any... how did they add their name to the bios splash in the first place?

Comment: @josh: Perhaps some internal tool that Dell used to customise all the PCs of a bulk order from the institution?

Answer (score 2):

**Option A** This method might be what you're looking for. Please know you have my warning when trying to do things with a BIOS. [How can I change my BIOS splashscreen?](https://superuser.com/questions/116507/how-can-i-change-my-bios-splashscreen)

**Option B** Since this is a Dell the BIOS could have also been configured via [Dell CCTK](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1952.dell-client-configuration-toolkit-cctk.aspx). This is a management utility that will allow you to configure BIOS settings for any Dell Optiplex/Latitude/some XPS machines. I have never used it to set up a custom BIOS image and I am not sure if it will allow you to change such a setting. You can build a file with the settings you want and run it all from within Windows.