# Motherboard with my company's logo on the boot screen

Tags: bios, uefi, splash

How can I put my company's logo on the boot screen of my systems? Is it possible? How do the other computer manufacturers like Dell (and other manufacturers too) do it, and from where do they produce their logos on the boot screen?

Comment: Manufacturers like Dell either manufacture their own motherboards or pay to have it manufactured to their own custom spec. I have encountered motherboards on which the logo is burned into a static ROM and cannot be changed by any software mean. At least, you should name a make or model of the motherboard to get a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change my BIOS splashscreen?](http://superuser.com/questions/116507/how-can-i-change-my-bios-splashscreen)

Answer (score 1):

duplicate:[How can I change my BIOS splashscreen?](https://superuser.com/questions/116507/how-can-i-change-my-bios-splashscreen)

As the above question's answer tells that the splash screen is usually coded into the BIOS, it maybe possible if you flash the BIOS with custom reverse engineered firmware. But I don't know that is legal to do it. It can also destroy the motherboard.

Comment: A duplicate isn't an answer. Rather the question needs to be flagged as a duplicate rather than answering it. Perhaps you meant to add this as a comment?

Comment: I haven't got the reputation to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Actually ASUS boards offer that option standard.  At least in their high end models.

page 151 of this manual for example.

https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_990FX_R20/HelpDesk_Download/

[image]