# How to change logo on with ASROCK UEFI BIOS

Tags: boot, uefi

I have an ASROCK motherboard that boots with a UEFI bios, and I have been trying to change the logo.  I tried using the 8oot tool, which simply didn't work.  I also tried using HackBGRT which told me it couldn't find the EFI partion.  What do I need to do to change it?
    I found updated versions of the BIOS, but I couldn't extract the files within them like the accepted answer from [How can I change my BIOS splashscreen?](https://superuser.com/questions/116507/how-can-i-change-my-bios-splashscreen) suggests I should be able to.  Any suggestions?  (I tried both WinRAR and 7-ZIP both said the archive format was corrupted or not an archive.)

I downloaded the drivers (DOS, Windows and Flash) from Here: https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H97%20Pro4/#BIOS

Comment: I have been unable to follow the accepted answer there, as neither 7-zip nor WinRAR were able to unpack the bios when I downloaded it.